# Counterexample to demonstrate there are no functional dependencies

Tags: relational-theory

For instance in the following example

> Let be F={AB→C, B→D, CD→E, CE→GH, G→A}
>
> Do we have AB→G?

We don't have any functional dependencies.

I am able to show a functional dependency when it works but how to show a counterexample when it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find if the functional dependency AB→G is implied by F you should find the closure of the attributes AB under F, i.e. AB<sup>+</sup>.

These are the steps:

```
AB+ = AB
      ABC     (using AB→C)
      ABCD    (using B→D)
      ABCDE   (using CD→E)
      ABCDEGH (using CE→GH)
```

and since G belongs to AB<sup>+</sup>, then AB→G can be derived from F.